# Get value or null of nullable variable

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

With C# 6 I have the following model:

```
public class Model {
  public Int32? Result { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following (example code):

```
Model model = new Model();     
Int32 result = model.Result.Value;
```

If Result is null I get an error so I need to use:

```
Int32 result = model.Result.HasValue ? model.Result.Value : 0;
```

Is there a shorter way to do this in C# 6?

Comment: why not `Int32? result`

Comment: You can use `GetValueOrDefault` but this give you `0` for `Int32` (you cannot assign null to `Int32`).

Comment: Your example won't compile since `null` is not a value of type `Int32`. Do you want to use `0` instead?

Comment: what value do you want `result` to be when `Result` is null?

Comment: @un-lucky My code is just an example ... The Int32 result is in fact something from another model ...

Comment: You need to fix your question. Your code example is broken (i.e. assigning `null` to `Int32`), so we don't know what you're trying to do. I assume you're trying to shorten: `Int32 result = model.Result.HasValue ? model.Result.Value : 0;`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the null-propagating operator with the null conditional operator to provide a default value.

```
Model modelWithNullValue = new Model();
Model modelWithValue = new Model { Result = 1};
Model modelThatIsNull = null;
Int32 resultWithNullValue = modelWithNullValue?.Result ?? -1;
Int32 resultWithValue = modelWithValue?.Result ?? -1;
Int32 resultWithNullModel = modelThatIsNull?.Result ?? -2;
Console.WriteLine(resultWithNullValue); // Prints -1
Console.WriteLine(resultWithValue); // Prints 1
Console.WriteLine(resultWithNullModel); // Prints -2
```

Edit: As of C# 7.2, the following syntax is also valid for setting a default value in this kind of situation.

```
Model badModel = null;
var result = badModel?.Result ?? default;
var pre72 = badModel?.Result ?? default(int);
Console.WriteLine(result); // 0
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().Name); // Int32
```

Comment: You can use `??` with `model.Result` directly: `int result = model.Result ?? -1;`

Comment: @JonathonChase You cannot use ?.Value

Comment: @MiguelMoura I've edited with a more complete implementation using both null operators as an example, assuming your implementation of Model.